# Python regex to retrieve number, dot and dash from unicode

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have this data: `u'US $1.37 - 2.65'`

And I want to retrieve `1.37-2.65`.

**Important**:
The `US $` part is not static and it may change depending on the type of currency selected. Other examples:

```
34.27 - 47.92 грн.
€ 1.05 - 1.47
NZ$ 16.57 - 18.22
```

In other words, the regex should only retrieve:

- numbers
- dots between numbers
- dash between numbers

Comment: `data.split('$')[1]`.

Comment: What is the general format for the data?

Comment: The `US $` part is not static and it may change depending on the type of currency selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can just split on the "$" character and use the second list entry:

```
>>> u'US $1.37 - 2.65'.split("$")[1]
u'1.37-2.65
```

If you need to use regex for some reason, the following should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('^.* \$([0-9 -.]+)$', 'US $1.37 - 2.65')[0].replace(' ', '')
'1.37-2.65'
```

Final edit:  The following pattern will match any of the examples added in the edits to the original post:

```
>>> re.findall('^(.* [^0-9]?)?([0-9.,]+ - [0-9.,]+)( .*)?$', data)[0][1].replace(' ', '')
```

Comment: The 'u' character in front just means it's represented as unicode, because the input string was unicode. It's logically equivalent to an ASCII string.

Comment: i know that but while parsing it as a data it should not be there as a result desired.

Comment: I just added some more information to my question. The `US $` part of the string may change depending on the currency selection.

Comment: @FTM Then change the regex pattern to account for that: `re.findall('^.* .([0-9.]+ - [0-9.]+)$', 'US $1.37 - 2.65')[0].replace(' ', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found something that works for all currencies.

`"".join(re.findall('[0-9.-]',text)).rstrip(".")`

Where `text` works with any of these:

```
34.27 - 47.92 грн.
€ 1.05 - 1.47
NZ$ 16.57 - 18.22
```

Answer (score -2):

```
aa = 'US $1.37 - 2.65'
string = ""
flag = 0
for i in range(len(aa)):
    if flag ==1:
        string += aa[i]
    if aa[i] == '$':
        flag=1

print(string)
```

and

```
aa = 'US $1.37 - 2.65'
index = aa.find('$')
newstring = aa[index+1:]
print(newstring)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer needs more explaination about how the code solves the problem.